# I cant run any python programs in VSC

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010

This is what it looks like in my terminal  It was recommended that the forward slashes in the second part need to be back slashes. How did that happen?
this is what I'm looking for
"""  C:\Users\mikes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
c:\Users\mikes\Downloads\First Project\my_program.py

```
      and this is what's in my terminal
      "C:/Program Files/Python310/python.exe" 
    "c:/Users/mikes/Downloads/First Project/my_program.py"
   -bash: C:/Program Files/Python310/python.exe: No such fil"""
```

Answer (score 0):

I do recommend replacing the forward slashes with two backward slashes. Sometimes that is needed so python won't mix the address up with something else. You could also go to your program in VSC, click the run button, and then click the run without debugging button: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl2Pj.png).

I hope you have found this answer useful. Best of luck on your program! :)

Comment: Thanks but I downloaded spydder and I have no issues, something must be up with VSC.

Comment: I agree, good luck on your program! I bet it will turn out great! :D